Permissions needed reading picture from gallery using MediaStore API
Consider implementing an app, that lets users pick images taken with a camera from Gallery, and then use those pics on the app.
Project settings are
targetSdk=34, compileSdk=34, minSdk=22

Using MediaStore API, picker can be launched
startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) ,1);

and then acquire a picture in onActivityResult()
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    val uri = intent!!.data!!
    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!
    val bitmapBytes = inputStream.readBytes()
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.size)
}

Question 1:
What permissions are needed to produce Bitmap? Reading specs it seems that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would be needed. But the code works without any permission in SDK 34-24, and starts only requiring READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on <= SDK 23.
Question 2:
Why READ_MEDIA_IMAGES is not needed on >= SDK 33? As it states on another specs, implementation needs that permission to read images other app produced on SDK 33 onwards.
Question 3:
What would be the advantage of using PhotoPicker API (instead of MediaStore)?


What permissions are needed to produce Bitmap?

If the Uri has a content scheme (and they all should on modern versions of Android), you should already have permission, courtesy of the user being involved in the selection via ACTION_PICK.

starts only requiring READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on <= SDK 23

Your Uri presumably has the file scheme on those older devices.

Why READ_MEDIA_IMAGES is not needed on >= SDK 33?

See above.

What would be the advantage of using PhotoPicker API (instead of MediaStore)?

You are not using MediaStore. You are using ACTION_PICK. What handles ACTION_PICK for a MediaStore-supplied Uri varies by OS version. On the most recent versions of Android, it might be the PhotoPicker — I have not used ACTION_PICK seriously in several years.
The PhotoPicker API:

Supports multiple images, which ACTION_PICK does not

Supports cloud providers (sometimes), which ACTION_PICK may or may not


